# Web application product shows "Not secure" warning on browsers

Tags: web-applications, https, localhost, websecurity, security-warning

I am working on a web application product that is to be distributed to several clients. Now everything was fine as long as customers used localhost but when they used the server IP to access web application's password page, Chrome and other browsers started showing "Not secure" on the title.
I know about self signing but I am sure that it is not the possible solution for web product where every user will have to create signing authority and setup the signature or at lease create signing authority.

Answer (score 0):

If the server certificate is self-signed is not responsibility of the user to create anything. The server must be configured to use a CA signed certificate that the browser will be able to verify it's identity.

Browsers pre-trust many known CA root certificates. If your web application has a server certificate signed by a known CA, the user will not receive any errors in the browser, since it will be able to verify the application's own identity.

There are plenty of resources online explaining how to create a CSR and get it signed by a CA (it may involve extra costs).

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I am still not sure what it means and If I'll have to google it, what should be my search keywords etc.

Comment: Configuring SSL for an application without proper security background it's not recommended, however searching for the exact phrase I've written will return great results: "how to create a CSR and get it signed by a CA". Remember to check the documentation of the language/tools you're using on how to properly configure SSL on it.